# Regex to split out sentences including their punctuation, but not on titles (Mr., Mrs., etc.)

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to get a regex that will split text into sentences, leaving in the punctuation (breaking on the space after the punctuation but not breaking on titles.

I'm almost there.

```
@"(?<=[\.!;\?])\s+"
```

splits on the space, but also splits on the title.

```
@"(?<!Mr|Mrs|Dr|Ms|St|a|p|m|K)\.|;"
```

won't split on titles but wipes out the punctuation.

Any suggestions on combining the two expressions so that the regex will split on space after the punctuation but not split on titles?

Example Text:

> Shirking and sharking in all their many varieties have been sown broadcast by the
>       ill-fated cause; and even those who have contemplated its history
>       from the outermost circle of such evil have been insensibly tempted
>       into a loose way of letting bad things alone to take their own bad
>       course, and a loose belief that if the world go wrong it was in some
>       off-hand manner never meant to go right.
>
> Thus, in the midst of the mud and at the heart of the fog, sits the
>   Lord High Chancellor in his High Court of Chancery.
>
> "Mr. Tangle," says the Lord High Chancellor, latterly something
>       restless under the eloquence of that learned gentleman.
>
> "Mlud," says Mr. Tangle. Mr. Tangle knows more of Jarndyce and
>       Jarndyce than anybody. He is famous for it--supposed never to have
>       read anything else since he left school.
>
> "Have you nearly concluded your argument?"
>
> "Mlud, no--variety of points--feel it my duty tsubmit--ludship," is
>       the reply that slides out of Mr. Tangle.
>
> "Several members of the bar are still to be heard, I believe?" says
>       the Chancellor with a slight smile.

Comment: Does this make sense to anyone? Try rephrasing your question

Comment: He wants to split a paragraph of text by sentences, so by a `.`.  But the `.` appears in places besides the end of a sentence (i.e. `Mr.`).  Those shouldn't be split up.

Answer (score 2):

This effectively combines what you're looking for:

```
 @"(?<!(?:Mr|Mr.|Dr|Ms|St|a|p|m|K)\.)(?<=[.!;\?])\s+"
```

However, i don't think it's reliable. What if a sentence finished with something like "abaracadabra."?

Comment: I found  @"(?<=[\.!;\?])(?<!Mr\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.|Ms\.|St\.|P\.M\.|K\.)\s+" works - Split on space after period, etc. but not on space after Mr., etc.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this works:

```
(?<=[\.!;\?])(?<!Mr\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.|Ms\.|St\.)\s+
```

Comment: What about Rd.? Or any other abbreviation you didn't list yet?

Comment: That's a good point, any other abbreviation would cause a split. In fiction, however, abbreviations like Rd. never appear. Since I'm splitting up sentences found in fiction, I've decided I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Rd. meaning Road and Pl. Meaning Place in an address can appear. Also Esq., Jr. and Sr.

Comment: Esq. and Jr. do appear in the data so I've added them to the regex. Thanks!